# List of dictionaries - how to read a specific value in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list

```
lis = [{'score': 12, 'name': 'random_content', 'numrep': 11}, {'score': 31, 'name': 'some_content', 'numrep': 10}]
```

How can I read a value of a specific key in this list?
i.e. A score value for a name: 'some_content' from above list which is equal to 31.

Comment: Explain this a bit more. What if two or more maps had the "some_content" key?

Comment: The assumption is that some_content is unique

Comment: If you have a unique name that you're going to be using for lookups, why are you using a list instead of a dict with that name for the key?

Comment: I decided to use list, as I need to sort often by score. Can this kind of sorting be done on dict?

Comment: @Macin You can't sort a dict, but you can get a sorted list of keys, values or (key,value) by using sorted on a dict : `sorted(dic.items(), key = lambda x:x[1]['score'])`

Comment: I can't see how this is a duplicate. The "Python search dictionary..." is an attempt to locate a key/value pair with a key that looks like something in ONE dictionary. In this current question the OP has several maps of which one of the maps contain an exact key the user is interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Better use a `dict` here to get fast lookups for any `'name'`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
lis = [{'score': 12, 'name': 'random_content', 'numrep': 11}, {'score': 31, 'name': 'some_content', 'numrep': 10}]
dic = defaultdict(dict)
for d in lis:
    for k,v in ((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if k != 'name'):
        dic[d['name']][k] = v
```

Now `dic` looks like:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>,
{'random_content': {'score': 12, 'numrep': 11},
 'some_content': {'score': 31, 'numrep': 10}
})
```

Get the score for `'some_content'` in `O(1)` time:

```
>>> dic['some_content']['score']
31
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehesion, generator expression:

```
>>> [x for x in lis if x['name'] == 'some_content']
[{'score': 31, 'name': 'some_content', 'numrep': 10}]
>>> [x['score'] for x in lis if x['name'] == 'some_content']
[31]
>>> next(x['score'] for x in lis if x['name'] == 'some_content')
31

>>> next(x['score'] for x in lis if x['name'] == 'ome_content')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> next((x['score'] for x in lis if x['name'] == 'no-such-content'), 'fallback')
'fallback'
```